# How to write a program that will ask you your name, then display 'Hello Name' where 'name' is the name you have entered in python 3.3.4?

Tags: python, variables, input

E.g:

```
What is your name?
Anna
Hello Anna
```

I have already tried something that goes;

```
print
var = (input("What is your name? ")
print:("you entered", var)
```

But all I receive is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Your script has quite a few issues:

1. Since you are not actually calling the `print` function, the first line is doing nothing.  I would recommend that you just remove it. It is not needed.
2. There is an extra opening parenthesis on the second line:

   ```
   var = (input("What is your name? ")
   #   --^
   ```
3. There is a colon on the third line, which is illegal syntax:

   ```
   print:("you entered", var) 
   #  --^
   ```
4. To get the prompt to look like your example, you need to add a newline (`\n`) to the end of it.

Below is a fixed version of your script:

```
var = input("What is your name?\n")
print("Hello", var)  # I also put "Hello" here, like in your example
```

Demo:

```
What is your name?
Anna
Hello Anna
```